# What does Travis-CI actually do in PHP development?

Tags: php, travis-ci

I'm new to OpenSource project. Some projects which I browse use Travis. I have read the manual, but still cannot get what actually this Travis CI doing.

Could anyone explain it or give some links?

Comment: CI stands for [Continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TravisCI (as the CI) suggests, is a "Continuous Integration" environment. Whenever you commit code changes, it can execute the unit tests, and other tools such as codesniffer, mess detection, copy-paste detection, document builder, etc.

Even more useful, it can run your tests against different versions of PHP.

It can then report on the results of those test and tools runs, so you always know whether your changes are stable or not, or have broken other parts of the code, etc.

Comment: Hmm.. do you have some link on tutorial to setup web development using travis-ci, anyway i'm using Yii framework.
Thanks @mark-baker

Comment: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/getting-started/

Comment: i found some interesting article here..
http://vzmind.tumblr.com/post/9412611799/why-travis

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/travis-ci-what-why-how/